# Why date pipe with input type text does not work with angular2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date-pipe

**This works :**

**DetailEvent** is a object which has start_time of type **Date**

```
 <span class="month">{{DetailEvent.start_time   | date: 'MMM'}}</span>
```

**This does not work:**

```
 <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]='DetailEvent.start_time| date: 'MMM''> <span class="calender-to">to</span> </div>
```

Comment: What is `DetailEvent`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer its just a object with starttime as date

Comment: why downvote here?

Comment: What kind of date? String, or `Date` type?. What's the problem you run into?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer your answer works

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess it's because it doesn't contain the information necessary to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes generally don't work with `two-way-binding

```
[(ngModel)]='fromDate | date: 'MMM''
```

should be

```
[ngModel]="fromDate | date: 'MMM'" (ngModelChange)="fromDate = $event"
```

Comment: The 1st code line (your code with `[(ngModel)]`) is just a short form of the 2nd line (my code). The short form doesn't work if the expression is not a simple reference because how would `ngModel` be able to assign a value to `fromDate | date: 'MMM'`?